# How to set a hidden property on a view controller in Xamarin iOS once it has been set by another class with a CA Transition

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

[image: This is what the layout looks like]

I have a `UI ViewController` that has a `UITableView` controller embedded in it by means of a `Container View` and an `Embed` segue.

So when the user clicks on the menu, a sliding menu pops out by means of a `CATransition`. On this menu, one of the options is "Home" that moves the menu back to it's original position and sets the Hidden property of this `TableView Controller` to `true`.

The next time you click on the Menu button, the menu does not pop out because the `TableView Controller`'s `Hidden` property was set to `True` in it's class when we clicked on the `Home` button.

**Summary**
Thus the problem is that once the user clicks on the `Menu` button, the current class needs to be able to set the hidden property of a `TableView` controller that is defined in another class.

I guess this is more to do with interaction between classes than mobile development, but I included the whole scenario as background.

What is the best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: Don't expect people editing your question are actually able to answer it. There is a Review queue, which anyone can dig into and start improving posts. You might want to elaborate what your mean with current and previous class. Maybe also include some code or minimal reproduction steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: But what are those classes? UIViewController? Something else?

Comment: You can't do that in the comments.

Comment: Can't you use the ParentViewController property to get hold of Class A and set the Hidden property?

Comment: By way of a delegate?

Comment: From the code behind for that Home button. You should be able to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional constructor in the main class that excepts a `parameter` of type `UITableView`. Then pass the `UITableView` of `class` B as a `parameter` to the new `constructor` of the main `class`. Then you can work with it from there.